# Why does SWI-Prolog unify a quoted and unquoted string (without spaces) to the same rule?

Tags: prolog, unification, iso-prolog, unify

Assume I have the following rules:

```
unify('test', 'this is a test').
run :- write('Enter something: '), 
       read(X), 
       unify(X, Y), 
       write('The answer is '), write(Y).
```

And then I run it as follows:

```
?- ['unify.pl'].
% unify.pl compiled 0.00 sec, -48 bytes
true.

?- run.
Enter something: test.
The answer is this is a test
true.

?- run.
Enter something: 'test'.
The answer is this is a test
true.
```

Why does SWI-Prolog unify both `test` and `'test'` to `unify('test', 'this is a test').`? I came across this while answering a Prolog question on SO. While I was able to answer the person's question, I couldn't explain this particular behavior, and I was wondering if any one else could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While atoms in SWI-PROLOG can be denoted using single quotes, e.g, `'This is an atom'`, single quotes are **not needed** when the SWI-PROLOG parser can identify an atom from a sequence of characters, usually starting with a lowercase alphabetic character, such as `test`. If the sequence contained whitespace (or some other characters), you'd need the single quotes to denote an atom properly. Alphanumeric characters and certain punctuation characters like underscore `_` are fine, e.g., `test5_6`.

If the character sequence without single quotes were to start with anything else, such as a number `6k`, the parser will treat it as a `number`; if it were an uppercase alphabetic character such as `Test`, the parser will treat it as a variable.

Comment: Ah, is this SWI-Prolog-specific behavior?

Comment: @Vivin Paliath: Perhaps, at least with SWI-PROLOG, though it seems typical of other PROLOG implementations I have seen as well. But nevertheless, yes, it is something the SWI-PROLOG parser will do in particular, perhaps if only to save you from having to single-quote all your atoms :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is not SWI specific behavior - it is required by the standard.
There is a simple way to see this. You can use this also for
any other term whose syntax is not evident. Either type at the toplevel:

```
?- X = 'test'.
   X = test.
?- X = 'this is a test'.
   X = 'this is a test'.
```

The answer is always valid Prolog text - this is specific to SWI but
also to many other Prolog systems like YAP, GNU, B, IF, SICStus.

Another way to see this is to use write_canonical/1:

```
?- write_canonical('this is a test').
'this is a test'
   true.
?- write_canonical([a,b,(c,d),{e,f}]).
'.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(','(c,d),'.'({}(','(e,f)),[]))))
```